# SSRS HTML rendering and styling

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to set some styling for specific tags in SSRS when using HTML rendering in a text box?

I have some text that I show as HTML. This text is often wrapped with P tags. When this happens, SSRS then renders spaces since that's the default formatting for P tags. I want to get rid of those spaces in between paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you remove **P** tag from the field? for instane you can use the following expression

```
(Fields(YourColumn.Value).Replace("<p ","")).Replace("</p>","")
```

Comment: I followed this approach. Avoid having p tags in the content

Comment: Was it helpful? If it worked, please mark it as answer for upcoming users. tnx